# Get modified time of file-1 and insert into file-2

Tags: bash, touch, zsh, cat, ls

I am a self-learner just starting to learn bash and shell scripting using lectures and material from a course at MIT called [./missing semester](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/)

I have just completed the first lecture and most of the exercises, but I am stuck on Exercise 9 specifically. The goal is to use `>` and `|` to grab the last modified date of a file `semester` and input that into a new file `last-modified.txt`.

I've read through the help and man pages of `touch`, `ls`, `stat` and `cat`, but I cannot figure out a way to grab only the last modified date of the target file. I know I am missing the connection between using the output of one program and piping that into the input of another program. Here's what I've tried so far using WSL2 on Windows 10. My shell is zsh.

[Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xCvN.png)

[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoiWw.png)

If anyone has any resources to point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason that you are learning bash and use zsh? You used both shells as a tag, but you need to clarify, whether you need a bash or a zsh solution.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for pointing this out. As a beginner, I didn't realize there was a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stat` command to get the info, instead of `ls`.

The `-c` option lets you specify certain file information in a certain format - depending on what info you need exactly, the parameter to this option will be different.

(from the [stat man page](https://ss64.com/bash/stat.html)):

```
    %x     Time of last access, human-readable
    %X     Time of last access, seconds since Epoch
    %y     Time of last data modification, human-readable
    %Y     Time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
    %z     Time of last status change, human-readable
    %Z     Time of last status change, seconds since Epoch
```

So, assuming you want a human-readble time of last data modification, use:

`stat -c %y semester`

You can use `>` to write the result to another file

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and it worked.

./semester | head -n12 | tail -n1 > last-modified.txt

head outputs the first 12 lines, then tail outputs the last line, and lastly the output gets put into last-modified.txt